# How to get a single .gitignore after git svn create-ignore

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have imported SVN repository with Git using:

```
git svn clone --preserve-empty-dirs --stdlayout svn+ssh://... SVN.git
```

It did succeed in the end although on the way it did fail few times and I had to "restart" with

```
git svn fetch
```

Yet it seems in the end everything is fine. (Although now when writing I start to wonder whether I should have provided `--preserve-empty-dirs` in the additional `fetch`es as well? **EDIT:** *No, I should not. See my comment bellow.*)

Then I wanted to create `.gitignore` and so I did with

```
git svn create-ignore
```

And this succeeded as well.

But the end result is less than satisfying. It did generate lots of `.gitignore` files in many folders. It seems that each time when SVN had a `svn:ignore` property Git created corresponding `.gitignore` file.

While I would like to have them merged into a single root `.gitignore` file. This is possible with git since its far more flexible with ignores allowing to ignore in sub-directories with wildcards (or without them). Any way I think it is possible to automatically transform those "sub-`.gitignore`s" into a single one at the root.

And I would like to have that because "SVN people" would not be happy with me committing over twenty `.gitignore` files...

Comment: It seems `git svn fetch` does not accept `--preserve-empty-dirs` (judging from what `git help svn` shows) so that answers my doubt.

Comment: indeed "git svn fetch" doesn't tag that flag, but you can add those to .gitconfig, like: `[svn-remote "svn"]preserve-empty-dirs = true` . In order to activate it, you will also need to add: `[svn-remote "svn"]added-placeholder = .gitignore`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to use `show-ignore` instead of `create-ignore` and save the output to a file.

So after cloning the repository execute following command:

```
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
```

from the repository root where you have the `.git` directory.

Comment: When I did this it created a .gitignore file with Unicode encoding.  This made the ignore silently fail until I manually changed the encoding of .gitignore to UTF-8.